# Mac won't let me type certain words

Tags: macos, keyboard, autocorrect

I keep on getting misspelt words in emails, Google searches, etc. because my Mac won't let me type certain words. No matter how carefully I spell them, it changes them to something else.

How can I stop my Mac from typing things for me?

Comment: what mac, what OS X

Comment: A MacBook. Yes, running MacOS X.

Comment: Buscar is asking for the Model of Macbook and the **version** of macOS on your MacBook. That will help us give you the correct information. In fact if it is not some kind of Mac running macOS X you would be directed elsewhere. So versions and *details* are important.

Answer (score 2):

Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Text

disable the Automatic correction

[image]